# Shopping cart with Angular - Conditionally set default items

Tags: angularjs

Stuck AngularJS newbie here...
I'm working on an online food order system. User is supposed to choose among different cuisines. For each cuisines a number of default menus is shown. For each menu a number of default courses is proposed. The user should have the option to change such default courses, add and/or remove additional courses, etc.
Where I'm stuck is the creation of default courses for each menu. Tried with filters, ng-if, etc. but no solution seems to work.
For instance assuming user has chosen Italian cuisine > Margherita menu, I would like to list 3 courses: 'Pizza', 'Salad', 'Softdrink' each with its options and extras.
Courses' details to be picked up from the $scope.courses array (including all available courses with price details, available extras, etc.).

Take a look to the code snipped [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3AHzhv2eYpcsQtvIYZb?p=preview). Html extract:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div>
<label>Type of Menu:</label>
  <select ng-model="selectedToM"
    ng-options="menu.ToM group by menu.ToC for menu in menus">
  </select><br>

<h3>Personalize Your Menu</h3>
<label>Course: </label>
  <select ng-model="SelectedCourse" 
    ng-options="course.Type for course in courses">
    <option value="">-- choose an option --</option>
  </select>

<div ng-repeat="Characteristic in SelectedCourse.Characteristics">
  {{Characteristic.Label}}:
  <select ng-model="SelectedCharacteristic" 
    ng-options="option.OptItem for option in Characteristic.Options">
  </select>
</div>
```

and app.js extract:

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.menus = [{
    ToC: 'American',
    ToM: 'McMenu',
    courses: []
  }, {
    ToC: 'American',
    ToM: 'Easy',
    courses: []
  }, {
    ToC: 'Italian',
    ToM: 'Margherita',
    courses: ['Pizza', 'Salad', 'Softdrink']
  }, {
    ToC: 'Chinese',
    ToM: 'McNoodle',
    courses: []
  }, ];

  $scope.courses = [{
      "Type": "Pasta",
      "Ppu": 4,
      "Characteristics": [{
        "Label": "Variant",
        "Options": [{
          "OptItem": "Lasagne",
          "addppu": 2
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Tortellini",
          "addppu": 1.5
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Gnocchi",
          "addppu": 1
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Spaghetti",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Cannelloni",
          "addppu": 2
        }],
      }, {
        "Label": "Size",
        "Options": [{
          "OptItem": "Normal",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "King size",
          "addppu": 1
        }],
      }]
    }, {
      "Type": "Pizza",
      "Ppu": 4,
      "Characteristics": [{
        "Label": "Variant",
        "Options": [{
          "OptItem": "Margherita",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Napoli",
          "addppu": 1
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Funghi",
          "addppu": 1
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Prosciutto",
          "addppu": 0.5
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Hawaii",
          "addppu": 2
        }],
      }, {
        "Label": "Size",
        "Options": [{
          "OptItem": "Normal",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "King size",
          "addppu": 1
        }],
      }]
    }, {
      "Type": "Salad",
      "Ppu": 2.5,
      "Characteristics": [{
        "Label": "Dressing",
        "Options": [{
          "OptItem": "None",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Italian",
          "addppu": 1
        }, {
          "OptItem": "French",
          "addppu": 1
        }],
      }, {
        "Label": "Size",
        "Options": [{
          "OptItem": "Small",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Medium",
          "addppu": 1
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Large",
          "addppu": 1.5
        }],
      }]
    }, {
      "Type": "Softdrink",
      "Ppu": 3,
      "Characteristics": [{
        "Label": "Type",
        "Options": [{
          "OptItem": "Coca-Cola",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Coca-Cola Light",
          "addppu": 0.5
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Fanta",
          "addppu": 0
        }, {
          "OptItem": "Sprite",
          "addppu": 0
        }],
      }]
    }


  ];


});
```

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Please include all code needed to understand the question in the body of the question.

Comment: Hi Dave, here you go...